# Pandas to compare a column with list object with another column containing int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, operators

I have below panads dataframe where I want to compare between a list object(name in a list) of a column with an integer value in another column.

### Dataframe construct:

```
+------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Number     | Caller                | Assignment group     | Assigned to     | Status(state)      | Location   |   Aging |
|------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------|
| INC0722882 | Shivam Verma          | RD-DI-Infra-Linux    | Karn Kumar      | Active             | IN-NDA02   |       2 |
| INC0786494 | Kanhaiya Kumar Mishra | RD-Hotspot-Team-APAC | Karn Kumar      | Active             | IN-NDA02   |       5 |
| INC0790029 | Akhil Garg            | RD-DI-Infra-Storage  | Amit Raj        | Awaiting User Info | IN-NDA02   |       3 |
| INC0743690 | Japesh Kumar          | RD-DI-Infra-Linux    | Shakir Chaudhry | Awaiting User Info | IN-NDA02   |       5 |
+------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
```

### Pandas code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)

from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
##### Python pandas, widen output display to see more columns. ####
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
##########################################################################################
def pprint_df(dframe):
    print(tabulate(dframe, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql', showindex=False))

names = ['Amit Raj','Andre Geurts','Andrzej Kamionek','Ankur Wason','Ashish Kumar','Carl Thijssen','Chris Masson','Daniel Chorazy','Devarishi Kumar','Elizabeth Tamayo','Eric Oomen','Gopinath Perumal','Jakub Kubera','Jeffrey Thompson','Jeroen Kwanten','Karn Kumar','Kenny Henderson','Manish Kumar','Mihai Pârlea','Mihai Reus','Naveen Kumar','Rafiq Khan','Rob Goossens','Robert in','Roger Smith','Santhoshkumar Krishnamoorthy','Shakir Chaudhry','Sonu Kumar','Suraj Budha','Szymon Kolodziejski','Szymon Kubera','Tony Olsson','Vetrivelan Rajagopalan','Yogesh Miglani','Abrar Ahmad']

col_name = ['Number','Caller','Assignment group','Assigned to','Status(state)','Location','Aging']

df = pd.read_excel('Backlog-April_24.xlsx', usecols=col_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
# df  = df[df['Assigned to'].isin(names)]  <-- This works perfectly with above dataframe

df  = df[df['Assigned to'].isin(names) & df['Aging'] >= 5]
print(df.dtypes)
pprint_df(df)
```

When i ran the above code, i don't get results even i converted int to `str`.

```
$ ./pd_code.py
Number              object
Caller              object
Assignment group    object
Assigned to         object
Status(state)       object
Location            object
Aging               object
dtype: object
+----------+----------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+---------+
| Number   | Caller   | Assignment group   | Assigned to   | Status(state)   | Location   | Aging   |
|----------+----------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+---------|
+----------+----------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+---------+
```

### Desired output:

Example:

```
+------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Number     | Caller                | Assignment group     | Assigned to     | Status(state)      | Location   |   Aging |
|------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------|

| INC0786494 | Kanhaiya Kumar Mishra | RD-Hotspot-Team-APAC | Karn Kumar      | Active             | IN-NDA02   |       5 |

| INC0743690 | Japesh Kumar          | RD-DI-Infra-Linux    | Shakir Chaudhry | Awaiting User Info | IN-NDA02   |       5 |
+------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: I think the condition `df['Aging'] >= 5` should be between parenthesis, otherwise this part `df['Assigned to'].isin(names) & df['Aging']` is performed before `>=5`? and why do you convert Aging to string btw? I don't think you should otherwise comparing a string to an int won't work

Comment: @Ben.T, Good Suggestion, you mean `df[df['Assigned to'].isin(names) & (df['Aging'] > 3)]` ?

Comment: yes I think it should work like this, at least if the `isin` part is working as stated in your code

Comment: @Ben.T, you are absolutely correct, it worked, `convert Aging to string ` was just a stupid trial .. forgot to remove, now removed. thanks 

Comment: @KarnKumar I believe the solution suggested here, is the best solution for your problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of posterity, we need to use boolean indexing...

### Boolean indexing:

Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the data. The operators are: `|` for or, `&` for and, and `~` for not. These must be grouped by using parentheses.

```
df  = df[df['Assigned to'].isin(names) & (df['Aging'] >= 5)]
```

OR

```
df  = df[(df['Assigned to'].isin(names)) & (df['Aging'] >= 5)]
```

also there is a very nice detailed about [operator's precedence](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201175/should-i-use-parentheses-in-logical-statements-even-where-not-necessary) which is worth to read.